# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hope you're well. I'm trying to make it so when a float reaches zero after counting down from ten ( the counting down takes place in another script), another float (from another script) has ten added to it. Here's the code I've written:

```
public float timeLeft = 10f;    
public SeedNeed seedNeed;

public void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("IM READY TO HARVEST");
        Destroy(gameObject);
        seedNeed.currentNeed + 10;
                  
    }     
}
```

Anyway, the error I'm getting is: error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 6):

The error is saying your statement is invalid. It does not add 10 it produces a result but you're not assigning it to anything. I think you want this:

```
seedNeed.currentNeed += 10;
```

or this, I'm not sure

```
seedNeed.currentNeed = 10;
```